# Android shopify get product details query error

Tags: android, lambda, shopify, shopify-app

When I am trying to fetch product details by id in Shopify android using the code given below

```html
   ID id = new ID(productId);
        Storefront.QueryRootQuery query = Storefront.query(rootQueryBuilder ->
                rootQueryBuilder
                        .node(id, nodeQuery ->
                                nodeQuery
                                        .onProduct(productQuery ->
                                                productQuery
                                                        .title()
                                                .description()
        )
    )
);
        QueryGraphCall call = App.graphClient().queryGraph(query);
        call.enqueue(new GraphCall.Callback<Storefront.QueryRoot>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull GraphResponse<Storefront.QueryRoot> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull GraphError error) {

            }
        });

    }
```

But i'm am getting an error like **Argument 'id' on Field 'node' has an invalid value. Expected type 'ID!'**.

I have tried another code too but getting the same error

```html
        Storefront.ProductQueryDefinition query = q -> q
                .title()
                .descriptionHtml()
                .tags()
                .images(args ->  args.first(250), imageConnection -> imageConnection
                        .edges(imageEdge -> imageEdge
                                .node(Storefront.ImageQuery::src)
                        )
                )
                .options(option -> option
                        .name()
                        .values()
                )
                .variants(args ->  args.first(250), variantConnection -> variantConnection
                        .edges(variantEdge -> variantEdge
                                .node(variant -> variant
                                        .title()
                                        .availableForSale()
                                        .selectedOptions(selectedOption -> selectedOption
                                                .name()
                                                .value()
                                        )
                                        .price()
                                )
                        )
                );
        GraphCall<Storefront.QueryRoot> call = App.graphClient().queryGraph(Storefront.query(
                root -> root
                        .node(new ID(productId), node -> node
                                .onProduct(query)
                        )
                )
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what value you are feeding in productId?

Comment: is should be like this Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzI3ODA1MzI4OTk5NQ==

Answer (score 0):

Argument 'id' on Field 'node' has an invalid value. Expected type 'ID!'.

This error occurs when you are not feeding the correct productID . 
Try this -
Fetch collections -  `Storefront.QueryRootQuery query = Storefront.query(rootQuery -> rootQuery
                .shop(shopQuery -> shopQuery
                        .collections(arg -> arg.first(30), collectionConnectionQuery -> collectionConnectionQuery
                                .edges(collectionEdgeQuery -> collectionEdgeQuery
                                        .node(collectionQuery -> collectionQuery
                                                .title()
                                                .image(imageConnectionQuery -> imageConnectionQuery
                                                        .src()
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        );`

Now use collection id to fetch products of this collection -

```
 Storefront.QueryRootQuery query = Storefront.query(rootQuery -> rootQuery
            .node(new ID(collectionID), nodeQuery -> nodeQuery
                    .onCollection(collectionQuery -> collectionQuery
                            .products(
                                    args -> args
                                            .first(30),
                                    productConnectionQuery -> productConnectionQuery
                                            .pageInfo(pageInfoQuery -> pageInfoQuery
                                                    .hasNextPage()
                                            )
                                            .edges(productEdgeQuery -> productEdgeQuery
                                                    .cursor()
                                                    .node(productQuery -> productQuery
                                                            .title()
                                                            .productType()
                                                            .description()
                                                            .images(arg -> arg.first(10), imageConnectionQuery -> imageConnectionQuery
                                                                    .edges(imageEdgeQuery -> imageEdgeQuery
                                                                            .node(imageQuery -> imageQuery
                                                                                    .src()
                                                                            )
                                                                    )
                                                            )
                                                            .variants(arg -> arg.first(10), variantConnectionQuery -> variantConnectionQuery
                                                                    .edges(variantEdgeQuery -> variantEdgeQuery
                                                                            .node(productVariantQuery -> productVariantQuery
                                                                                    .price()
                                                                                    .compareAtPrice()
                                                                                    .title()
                                                                                    .available()
                                                                            )
                                                                    )
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            )
                            )
                    )
            )
    );
```

From response get all the product ids -

```
graphClient.queryGraph(query).enqueue(new GraphCall.Callback<Storefront.QueryRoot>() {

        @Override public void onResponse(@NonNull GraphResponse<Storefront.QueryRoot> response) {
            progress.dismiss();
            Storefront.Collection collection = (Storefront.Collection) response.data().getNode();
            boolean hasNextProductPage = collection.getProducts().getPageInfo().getHasNextPage();
            ArrayList  products = new ArrayList<>();
            String productID = new String[products.size()];
            for (Storefront.ProductEdge productEdge : collection.getProducts().getEdges()) {
                String productPageCursor = productEdge.getCursor();
                products.add(productEdge.getNode());
            }
        for(int count=0;count<products.size();count++){
        productID[count] = products.get(count).getId().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull GraphError error) {

        }
    });
```

Use these product id in your code .